# While running a .bat file with -D i am getting an error message

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am getting an error message like this when executing a bat file
"Sqlcmd: Warning: '-D' is an obsolete option and is ignored."

Comment: That a warning not an error message. Read it.

Comment: okay its a warning but how to avoid this warning?

Comment: Don't include the `-D` option. The warning says it's being ignored, so just leave it off since it's not being processed anyway.

Comment: got it -d should be used instead of -D